# DXL : How to list all attribute names in a current module?

Tags: ibm-doors

I wrote the code below to list all attributes in a module:

```
Module m = current
for objAttrName in m do {
    print objAttrName "\n"
}
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
- DXL: <Line:2> Incorrect arguments for (do)
```

I want that code to list all names of the attributes that exist in the current module

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to predefine the variable over which you want to iterate so DOORS knows what yo want to get: all objects in the module (type `Object`), all attribute types (type `AttrType`) in the module, all attribute definitions etc.

For your task, you can iterate over attribute definitions (type `AttrDef`).

This can be done using this loop

```
AttrDef ad
Module m = current
for ad in m do {
  if (ad.object) then print "object attribute " ad.name "\n"
  if (ad.module) then print "module attribute " ad.name "\n"
}
```

Edit: if you only want to iterate over all object attributes, not module attributes, you can use the the loop that you gave in the question (`for string in Module`), but you also need to define the variable, so, for your case just add the line

`string objAttrName`